# Which is the correct SE site for questions how to build social sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, social-networking

I had an idea for a social website which triggered a couple of questions. Which is the correct SE site to ask questions about building communities?

Comment: I'm not sure there's one yet. :)

Comment: And if we already knew the answers, sites would be flying out of Area51 much faster :)

Answer (score 6):

- [Answers.OnStartUp](http://answers.onstartups.com/) - For the business part (finance, hiring, management etc.) of the site
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) - If you're actually coding the site and are faced with a specific programming problem
- [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) - For managing the site itself, like hosting, SEO etc.

In short, nothing that's *specifically* about building websites, but these three should be suitable. Oh, and *do not* go to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), which is about **using** Webapps, not developing them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new proposal in area51: [Social Network Analysis](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24593/social-network-analysis)